# 802.11/ac Access point paired with 802.11/g router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

As it says in the tile I want to purchase an access point that supports 802.11/ac standard because I have tp-link archer t6e network card that supports 802.11/ac. If I do that will I get ac throughput or will my router be a bottleneck? I have Thomson tg782 router.

Comment: we don't know what your router is... or your line speed...

Comment: You get  new access point, wire it to your router... what speed is your router, what speed is your ISP connection... those are likely your bottleneck.

Comment: @Tetsujin I 'm not talking about download and upload speed.

Comment: You're not asking anything anyone can answer right now - including my questions to help you clarify.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think you understand my question... I want to know will I be able to use ac features from the access point even though I have a g router.

Comment: You're not going to be using the g router, by definition - unless you don't mean 'access point' at all, but mean 'network extender'

Comment: 802.11ac is backwards compatible with G, but you will not be able to fully utilize 802.11ac speeds if you go through the G router to the AC router, because 802.11g max throughput is 54 Mbps. LAN speeds will be affected, internet browsing may be, if you have 54 Mbps or faster. It all depends how you plan on using the router, which you have not explained in your question.

Comment: @DrZoo So if I want to get ac speeds I need to replace that g router that my ISP gave me?

Comment: Not if you're using the ac as an access point, as already mentioned. An access point uses wired ethernet to connect to your router. You didn't tell us anything about the router so no-one can say any more.

Comment: @Tetsujin ...So if I use ac as an access point and connect it via ethernet cable to my router I will get ac speeds ?

Comment: ...& I just discovered this is already a duplicate question & you provided the same lack of information on that too - https://superuser.com/questions/1220226/will-an-access-point-improve-network-performance

Comment: Nenad, Can you please edit your question to include the specific models you are referring to?

Comment: Between the router and the network card, the router is the bottleneck yes; however, if you have something else in your system that is another bottleneck then it doesn't matter. IE if you only pay for a certain internet speed.

Comment: I am sure you have seen a similar chart but here http://homenetworkadmin.com/wireless-b-vs-g-vs-n-vs-ac-difference/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Thompson TG782 appears to be a home gateway with a built-in ADSL2+ modem and 802.11g AP capabilities. Its LAN-side Ethernet switch is 10/100 only, not gigabit.

ADSL2+ maxes out at 25 Mbps, but almost no one gets that rate. Most ADSL2+ customers get less than 10Mbps.

802.11ac, in contrast, can do hundred of megabits per second. In the fairly common 3-stream VHT80 mode, it's not uncommon to see throughputs of 500Mbps or more.

So, by buying an 802.11ac AP with gigabit Ethernet LAN ports and an 802.11ac client card for a laptop, you could plug in, say, a PC or NAS to a LAN port on the new 802.11ac AP, and get 802.11ac rates between that PC/NAS and the AC laptop. HOWEVER, you won't get AC rates (hundreds of megabits per second) to/from the Internet.

You won't get AC rates to the Internet because your Thompson TG782's Internet connection, assuming you're using its ADSL2+ WAN port, is 25Mbps max, and you'd only get that maximum if you live next door to the phone company's central office or if the remote terminal equipment box for your neighborhood is basically in your front yard. So you won't get hundreds of megabits per second to/from the Internet if your Internet connection is ADSL2+. You need to upgrade to fairly high-end DOCSIS 3.0 (cable modem) service or fiber service to get hundreds of megabits per second.

You also won't get AC rates to the wireless or wired Ethernet LAN devices connected directly to your Thompson TG782, because its LAN ports max out at 100Mbps, which I would consider to be more like an 802.11n rate than an 802.11ac rate.

However, please note that your home gateway router (your TG782 in your case) doesn't get involved in LAN-to-LAN and LAN-to-WLAN traffic that only needs to go through your new 802.11ac AP. So traffic between your 802.11ac wireless client, through your 802.11ac AP, so a machine on Gigabit Ethernet connected into a LAN port of your 802.11ac AP, will be able to go at 802.11ac rates regardless of whether you still have a slow old TG782 at the head of your network.

P.S. On asking questions: The fact that you were asking if your ISP router would be your bottleneck is what made us wonder if you were asking about "to/from the Internet" speeds, not just "between devices within your home LAN" speeds. As you can see, to answer the "to/from the Internet" speed question, it was critical that we know the technical details of your ISP router. Technical questions require technical details. We love to help people with technical questions, but we get frustrated when people omit critical technical details and fail/refuse to add them even after being explicitly asked. Next time you ask a technical question, please include all the technical details you reasonably think may be related, and then if asked for more details, provide *all* the details requested, if at all possible.

Comment: would a better solution to be get a new router, call my ISP to set my current router to bridge mode and hook up my new ac router? Thanks for very detailed answer btw

Comment: @Nenad A better solution to what? If you want to get hundreds of megabits per second (802.11ac-like speeds) to/from the Internet, you'd have to ditch your ADSL2+ internet service and sign up for fiber service or high-end DOCSIS 3.0 cable modem service. Fiddling with settings on your Thompson router won't change the fact that ADSL2+ is obsolete and slow.

Comment: I'm not aiming for better download speed but greater router-pc-router soeeda

Comment: Then set your current router to just be a bridging ADSL2+ modem; disable its NAT service, disable its DHCP service, and disable its Wi-Fi AP service. Run an Ethernet cable between one of its LAN ports and the WAN port on your new 802.11ac router. Move all your home devices over to your new router so the only thing connected to your old ISP router is your new router.